# Why maven is compiling my java file even if it is in different folder inside the spring boot maven project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, compilation

I have a java file with a package declaration which is not the same as my project folder structure. I was expecting build will fail when I do `mvn clean install`, but the build was not failed, and I see class file is generated under the package which was declared in java file inside target folder. I am using `Java 11` along with `Spring Boot 2.2` in my project and I am using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

File: `EmployeeService.java` is placed inside folder `src/main/java/com/example/employeeservice/service`

```
package com.example.service

public interface EmployeeService {
   EmployeeDto createEmployee(CreateEmployeeDto createEmployeeDto);
}
```

When project is built using maven command `mvn clean install`, `EmployeeService.class` is getting generated inside `/target/classes/com/example/employeeservice/service`

Comment: maven will compile all sources in src/main/java - it does not know about spring boot. only spring boot will consider your base package for its context initialisation / component scan. The spring-boot-maven-plugin is not responsible for compiling, it re-packages the jar into an uber-jar so it can be run standalone. The maven compiler plugin does that work.

Comment: @wemu, understood. But problem is why maven compiled the java file having package declaration not same as project folder structure

Comment: can you add a file tree / folder structure to your question? I am not sure where your files are located in relation to the maven src/ folder

Comment: @wemu, I updated the question and added an example to understand the question better

Comment: I assume that just an example? the package does not match. But: why would you expect that class to not be compiled? It resides in the maven source directory: src/main/java - so it is considered. If you want to file to just "hang around" put it somewhere else out of src/main/java. Spring Boot has nothing to do with this. It is a maven default behavior. You can configure the compiler plugin to exclude some stuff: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludes

Comment: @wemu can't we restrict maven to check folder structure is same as package declaration

Comment: only sort if via the excludes of the compiler plugin. the package declaration is not really part of what maven knows. The question still remains: why put that file into src/main/java if you don't want it to be compiled? it will serve no purpose so just delete it?